# NullReferenceException When Attempting to Assign Label Text

Tags: vb.net, label

I received the following exception when I attempted to debug

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HomeWork Helper.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It came from this line of code in the AddControl Form Load Event

```
lblDescription.Text = "This Window is designed to set reminders for you for " & TypeAssign & "."
```

Here is the Declaration from a Module

```
Public TypeAssign As String
```

The Variable `TypeAssign` was assigned here before the form was opened

```
TypeAssign = "Tests"
frmControls.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: `Type` is a type or keyword in NET and it looks like you are using it as a variable.  try another name and see it that helps

Comment: Where do you write that line of code?

Comment: Changed it to `TypeAssign` but it did not work

Comment: Not in the form constructor?

Comment: It was assigned here: `TypeAssign = "Tests"  AddControl.ShowDialog()`

Comment: AddControl is the Form Load where `lblDescription.Text = "This Window is designed to set reminders for you for " & TypeAssign & "."` was called

Comment: edit your post to show the DECLARATION and ASSIGNMENT.  The error means you have declared something but not initialized.  no ambiguity

Comment: Could you add the whole code that builds up to the point where you assign that variable?

Comment: not very helpful - WHERE is it declared and where (in which event, procedure etc) does that assignment happen.  context matters. `assigned here the form was opened` does not tell us where it is assigned

Comment: set a breakpoint on the line where the error happens.  when the code stops, hold the mouse over `TypeAssign` then `lblDescription`.  For one of them, VS will report the value as `Nothing`.  Thats the problem -  something you think has been instanced, has not been.

Comment: @Plutonix lblDescription is what is nothing. I attempted to delete the label and create a new one under the name of lblHead, but the error stayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write that code in the form constructor, remember to put it after the call to InitializeComponent otherwise the control `lblDescription` is declared but it is not yet initialized, thus using the property Text leads to the NullReferenceException.

```
Public Class AddControl

     Public Sub New()
         InitializeComponent()
         lblDescription.Text = "This Window is designed to set reminders for you for " & _
                                TypeAssign 
     End Sub
```

Of course this will not work if TypeAssign is not visible inside the class AddControl. In this case the simple solution is to pass the variable through a new version of the Form constructor

```
Public Class AddControl

     Public Sub New(typeAssign as string)
         InitializeComponent()
         lblDescription.Text = "This Window is designed to set reminders for you for " & _
                                typeAssign 
     End Sub
```

This second version is called through

```
TypeAssign = "Tests"
AddControl frmControls = new AddControl(TypeAssign)
frmControls.ShowDialog()
frmControls.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Worked for me also, but I didn't got what you said... Constructor I never used neither the person who did the question... Can you explain this briefly please??? @Steve